# SPARQL - Max() isn't working

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, protege

I'm trying to execute this SPARQL query in PROTEGE 2000, but the MAX function isn't working. it's like Max() isn't accepting the type of ?cpt.

```
SELECT  ?searcher (COUNT(?publication) AS ?cpt)
WHERE {ont:GradeP ont:isFor ?searcher.
    ?publication ont:isPublishedBy ?searcher.}
GROUP BY ?searcher 
HAVING (MAX(?cpt))
```

here's the exception :

```
SparqlReasonerException: org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException: Unsupported value expr type: class org.openrdf.query.algebra.Max
```

> The request is working without `HAVING`, so i guess there is no problem
>   with my ontology.
>   So can please anyone tell me where is the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the expression supplied for `HAVING` evaluate to a boolean value? How do you think that is going to be achieved when all you provide is a numerical value returned from `MAX`?

Comment: Also, is your query missing some translations? In your first line, you are using a variable `?chercheur`, but in the `WHERE` clause, you are using `?searcher`.

Comment: It's searcher sorry i modified this wrong. you true about `HAVING` didn't pay attention.

Comment: the request's wanted meaning is : select the ?searcher who has Published the biggest number of ?publication(s). how can i achieve that ? any idea ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `group by` here, but maybe you have a reason. One way to do it is by using `order by`. I have provided an example on dbpedia.

```sql
select distinct ?x count(?y) as ?count
where{
    ?x a dbpedia-owl:Person.
    ?x dbpprop:author  ?y
}
order by desc(?count)
limit 1
```

The result is [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fx%20count%28%3Fy%29%20as%20%3Fcount%0D%0Awhere%7B%0D%0A%3Fx%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3APerson.%0D%0A%3Fx%20dbpprop%3Aauthor%20%20%3Fy%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20desc%28%3Fcount%29%0D%0Alimit%201%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on).

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working! couldn't get it to work without GROUP BY i still don't know why.

Comment: @Artemis That query isn't legal SPARQL (even if Virtuoso accepts it).  You can check with sparql.org's query validator.  That needs to be `(count(?y) as ?count)`,

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, so you only mean the braces are missing or the logic is at fault? The website was unavailable so I couldn't check.

Comment: Just the braces. The logic is fine. :)